# Compile C++ through Sublime Text and run in Mac Terminal

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text 3 and the build system integrated in it in order to compile C++ programs. I managed to write a build system to compile the whole project (all .cpp files in a directory) and then run in it Mac Terminal, however, the problem is that the working directory of Terminal is not the current folder, so I cannot use relative paths (for example) in C++ programs. Is there a way to fix this?

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "g++ -std=c++14 ${file_path}/*.cpp -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c++, source.cpp, source.cc, source.cxx",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run in Terminal",
            "shell_cmd": "g++ -std=c++14 ${file_path}/*.cpp -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' &&  open -a Terminal ./'${file_base_name}'",
            "shell": true,
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: There are ways to programatically (different on different platforms) a) obtain the current working directory. b) obtain the directory containing the currently executing program. Once you know those two things you should be able to either change the cwd to what you need *or* form a path to whatever resource you need, *relative to* your executable.

Comment: I agree, but I would like to write a relative path in my C++ program and for Sublime to set Terminal working dir in that folder.